# Do more distant galaxies move faster with respect to the cosmic background radiation rest frame?

Tags: cosmology, reference-frames, space-expansion, galaxies, cosmic-microwave-background

Aparently our galaxy is moving approximately 1/500th lightspeed with respect to cosmic background radiation.  While this is certainly fast, it stands to reason that it could had been a lot faster, so I will say we are pretty close to co-moving with respect to the big bang.
More distance galaxies move away from us faster and faster as per the the rules of the Hubble Constant.  Does this not create a weird problem, as it would imply the these more distance galaxies are less and less closely aligned with the rest frame of the universe?  How can this be explained philosophically as all galaxies in the universe are supposed to be more or less equal and ours just as ordinary.

Comment: They have their own CBR. The problem you see would exist if they would move faster respect to the latter.

Comment: How can they have their own CBR?  I thought that CBR is universal?

Comment: Sure it is universal. Hover is not a sphere located somewhere at fixed distance independent of the observer. Often the situation is resumed with *big bang happened everywhere*. There are quite some threads here on this point. Search for Big bang or Cosmic background.